# How to check if my C# app is using the right platform specific dll from nuget package?

Tags: c#, nuget

I'm busy adding support for multiple .net frameworks and platforms. The different frameworks seem to work. But if the right platform specific dll is used I don't really know how to check this. Now it seems that the MSIL/Any CPU version is always used...

**First the nuget package**

I followed the descriptions at:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/supporting-multiple-target-frameworks

And I'm also using .targets and .props files.

For the code look at Pullrequest Opensource project: https://github.com/lucascebertin/Serilog.Sinks.Burst/pull/1

**Using the nuget package**

When using the Nuget package everything seems to work. But currently I do 2 checks to see if the right platform dll is used. 
Note: The platform choice is MSIL/Any CPU, x86, and x64.

I do a diff between the dll in my package and the extracted/copyied one in the bin folder of the using project: Looks like the MSIL/Any CPU dll version is copyied.

The second check is from code to see which dll is used runtime:

```
   var oraSinkAsm = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Serilog.Sinks.Burst.Burst<>));
    Console.WriteLine("Using {0} from {1}", oraSinkAsm.FullName, oraSinkAsm.CodeBase);
    Console.WriteLine("Location: {0}", oraSinkAsm.Location);
```

Result is:

> Using Serilog.Sinks.Burst, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null from
>   file:///C:/Develop/Serilog.Sinks.Oracle/src/Serilog.Sinks.Oracle/Serilog.Sinks.Oracle.ConsoleTester/bin/x64/Release/net452/Serilog.Sinks.Burst.DLL
>   Location:
>   C:\Develop\Serilog.Sinks.Oracle\src\Serilog.Sinks.Oracle\Serilog.Sinks.Oracle.ConsoleTester\bin\x64\Release\net452\Serilog.Sinks.Burst.dll

So above bin\x64\Release\net452\Serilog.Sinks.Burst.dll looks to be the MSIL version:
[image]

The original builded version in my dist\build folder is:
[image]

So they should be the same but diff states: I386 vs. AMD64???

My questions:

- Does or Can the runtime C# use another dll than compiletime?
- Are above checks sufficient or do I need others?
- Is it really needed to build all platform flavors or is the MSIL/Any CPU dll sufficient?

Comment: Does your package contain any native architecture-specific assemblies? If not, you don't need to bother about including any runtimes folder in the package.

Comment: Thanks for your point! All assemblies are Managed code, but build for different platform targets. Do I need this for performance and/or efficiency?

Comment: If you ask, you most probably don't. The most common thing to do is to build against Any CPU in release mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is usually no need to include any architecture-specific folders in your package unless it contains any assemblies that specifically target ARM, x86, or x64. This typically applies only to native (non-.NET) assemblies that your C# code may wrap.

If your package contains only managed assemblies, the most common thing to do is to build against Any CPU in release mode.